# Creating a Y variable that's a count of the X variable

Tags: r, ggplot2, graph, count

This is a simple question and all the answers I've found have been for more complicated datasets.

I'm trying to create a line graph with X as dates and Y as a count of each individual X variable (the autogenerated 'rownames').

Have tried:

```
ggplot(data=o2outcomes, aes(x=transfusion_date, y=..count.., group=1)) +
  geom_line()

y x   
1 01/01/99 01:01,   
2 01/01/99 02:02,   
3 01/02/99 01:01
```

The code will be run frequently with new dates added, so I can't just assign the number of y variables as static 1,2,3, it needs to be a count of the x axis.

Comment: Hi Kate, can you put sample data using dput(o2outcomes) command and required output?

Comment: c("3/28/20 18:01", "3/28/20 22:16", "4/1/20 19:30", "4/1/20 23:56", 
"4/10/20 17:36", "4/10/20 20:30") is this what you meant? very new here thanks

Comment: do you want to combine c("3/28/20 18:01", "3/28/20 22:16") because they are falling on same day or keep them separated?

Comment: each date/time is a separate count thanks

Comment: seems to me like maybe I should create a vector of the count of x variables

Answer (score 2):

A plot with the y-variable equal to the count of the number of instances of each x-variable is easy in base R:

```
plot(table(x))
```

The `table()` function creates (as its name suggests) a table containing a vector of the number of occurrences of each value in x, with names corresponding to each x value.

To specify a line graph, we use the `plot` argument `type='l'`, and we can also (optionally) specify the y-axis limits to ensure that zero is included using `ylim=`.  Also, to make it a little prettier when using a vector of strings representing dates (which are usually too long to fit next-to-each-other if plotted horizontally as x-axis labels), we can use the `plot` argument `las=2` to display the x-axis labels vertically, and we can remove the x-axis title using `xlab=""`.

All together:

```
my_dates=c("3/28/20 18:01", "3/28/20 22:16", "4/1/20 19:30", "4/1/20 23:56", "4/10/20 17:36", "4/10/20 20:30","3/28/20 18:01", "3/28/20 22:16")

plot(table(my_dates),type="l",ylim=c(0,2),las=2,xlab="",ylab="# of each date/time")
```

[image]

Comment: this is great. I'm getting an error that:Error in plot.window(...) : invalid 'xlim' value my code looks like this 
my_dates=c( "3/28/20 18:01", 
                                "3/28/20 22:16", "4/1/20 19:30", "4/1/20 23:56", "4/10/20 17:36" 
                              )

plot(table(o2outcomes$transfusion_date),type="l",ylim=c(0,2),las=2,xlab="",ylab="1", "2", "3", "4")

view(o2outcomes$transfusion_date)

Comment: The ```my_dates=...``` bit is just a demo (I stole the demo data from @Harshal Gajare because it contains some duplicated date/times).

Comment: Did you include a  ```xlim=``` in your ```plot``` command?  If not, please could you try again with ```plot(table(head(o2outcomes$transfusion_date,10)))``` and see if you still get the error (this will indicate if it's possible to reproduce the error with a small dataset, which is easier to troubleshoot...)

Answer (score 1):

It's not as simple as you may believe in a first place. There is (to my knowledge) no direct way to use a count variable with `geom_line`. So (as also suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61838784/7941188)), it is better and easiest to first create a summary frame.

Here a pure tidyverse approach.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

dates <- data.frame(x = c("3/28/20 18:01", "3/28/20 22:16", "4/1/20 19:30", "4/1/20 23:56", "4/10/20 17:36", "4/10/20 20:30"))
dates <- 
  dates %>%
  mutate(x = as_date(mdy_hm(x))) %>%
  count(x) 

ggplot(data = dates, aes(x = x, y = n, group = 1)) +
  geom_line()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-05-16 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Thank you. Very basic follow up: where am I supposed to enter my dataset name o2outcomes or the variable 'date' (o2outcomes$transfusion_date)

Comment: dates <- 
  o2outcomes %>% select(transfusion_date) %>%
  mutate(date = as_date(mdy_hm(transfusion_date))) %>%
  count(date)

Answer (score 0):

try below code:

```
library(lubridate)
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)
a<-c("3/28/20 18:01", "3/28/20 22:16", "4/1/20 19:30", "4/1/20 23:56", "4/10/20 17:36", "4/10/20 20:30","3/28/20 18:01", "3/28/20 22:16")
b<-table(a) %>% as.data.frame()
b$a<-mdy_hm(b$a)
ggplot(b,aes(x = b$a, y = b$Freq, group = 1)) + geom_line()+ scale_x_datetime(labels = date_format("%d%b"))
```

[image]

Comment: something seems to fail in your aggregation